# Result of .prod in pandas gives me a inf number, how can I see the result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am aware of what `inf` represents.

What I am trying to do: I am trying to multiply every value present in my data frame.

```
variavel_de_transformacao_1=variavel_de_transformacao_1.prod(axis=0)
```

But as a result I am given an inf number that I can't represent. Can anyone help me ?

```
       return 
 1        1.000004
 2        1.000002
 3        1.000320
 4        0.999982
 5        0.998743
...
252       1.000432
```

But my result is :

```
 variável_de_transformacao_1= inf
```

Comment: Are any elements in the series equal to `inf`, or are they all ordinary finite numbers around 1.0, as in the first few rows?  This would be more answer-able with a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: there are none inf values

Comment: there are 252 lines of code, it wouldn't be wise, I believe, to display all the lines since they are exactly as the above.

Comment: Could you please post the data in the column (using say [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or [github gist](https://gist.github.com/)). It would make it much easier for us to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a `numpy.inf` somewhere in the Series.  If you are calculating returns with an expression like `final price / initial price`, then an `inf` value would occur wherever the initial price is zero.

You can verify this by calling:

```
>>> assert not numpy.isinf(variavel_de_transformacao_1).any()
>>> assert numpy.isfinite(variavel_de_transformacao_1).all()
```

I tried calling `prod` on a Series containing all positive values greater than 1.0, to see if it would overflow.

```
>>> s = pandas.Series(numpy.full(fill_value=1.01, shape=252))
>>> s.prod()
12.274002099240246
```

Trying with even larger numbers, the product is not `inf`:

```
for value in [1.0, 1.01, 1.05, 1.25, 1.50]:
    s = pandas.Series(numpy.full(fill_value=value, shape=252))
    print("{:4.2f}:    {:30.2f}".format(value, s.prod()))
```

```
Uniform elem. value             Product
1.00:                              1.00
1.01:                             12.27
1.05:                         218626.78
1.25:      2638294536026986064642048.00
1.50:    237135886481351290441812215478402248179974144.00
```